# When does an editor fail?

Tags: ethics, computer-science, editors, journal-workflow, responsibilities

Let's assume that a journal editor has been allocated a submission, started reviewing it himself, but stopped responding to the managing editor (= you) despite a long time since the authors had sent the submission (a little less than 3 years).  The submission is longer than each of the papers accepted during the last 5 years, but historically, even longer papers were accepted. The authors are aware of the length issue, but they are concerned.  The editor's Web page gets updated (say, new teaching contents appears), so, she/he is presumably still alive, but simply unresponsive.

The journal has no written, formal deadlines in its guidelines.  How long is it acceptable for the managing editor (= you) to wait after the first unanswered message to the editor before replacing the editor? What is typical in the field of computer science?

Comment: Seems a bit long. No, seems _very_ long. Time to contact them.

Comment: You haven't said how long it has been. If I haven't seen any changes in a month I'd worry. And if I'm the editor, I'd want an explanation of why the delays. And the response to the enquiry "why the delays" should come in a week or so. Maybe less. Time to put the stick about.

Comment: It probably depends on how long the paper is and maybe other factors, but I should think replacing him in -1.5 years would be quite reasonable (if you could get your hands on a time machine, that is). Dismissing him from the editorial board might also make more than a little sense.

Comment: In my initial reading I wasn't sure of your perspective, author or editor. I think you mean that you are the editor managing others.

Comment: @Just_A_Man I don’t have more to add, but this delay is obviously unacceptable. Hope you manage to figure out a path forward.

Comment: I would say that lack of communication is a failure in itself. No matter how long and no matter the fact that there is a paper on review stage. A total lack of communication is a failure in any concerted collaborative task or scenario.

Answer (score 3):

> How long is it acceptable for the managing editor (= you) to wait after the first unanswered message to the editor before replacing the editor?

If the lack of contact is unexpected and unannounced, then wait three weeks with weekly email reminders.

If it is expected or announced, then negotiate with the authors.  The authors might prefer to wait out an editor's absence if the editor has suitable expertise.

Answer (score 2):

I'd start getting concerned with no responses after about two weeks, and very concerned after about one month.

If the editor doesn't answer increasingly-urgent emails asking about the status, then I'd use different ways to contact them. The obvious way is to email their department receptionists. Alternatively, I might also phone the editor, or contact other people in their research group.

Three years is certainly way over the top; if a submission goes three years with no visible signs of being handled I would assume as an author that the journal is dead (and the publisher is being irresponsible, too).

Comment: I'm just dumbfounded that in *any* field, 2-3 years to get a paper through the first round of reviews would be considered "acceptable". It's a perspective that gives no priority at all to the paper whose papers are held up that long. How is one supposed to get tenure and promotion if processes take that long?

Comment: These days, if you need a phone call to communicate, it's impractical to be an editor.  Time zones alone rule it out.